# How can I usa this JavaScript code with more than 2 sections?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in javascript and Html and I created two scrolling button to go from section1 to section2.
What can I do if I need to have more than two sections?

```
function f1() {
        var elmnt1 = document.getElementById("sez1");
        elmnt1.scrollIntoView();
    }
    function f2() {
        var elmnt2 = document.getElementById("sez2");
        elmnt2.scrollIntoView();
    }
```

Comment: Use a class with contextual lookups.  Or depending on if they are bound to an event on the individual elements, a selector wouldn't be needed for the internal logic.

Comment: Add more functions?

Comment: `function goToSection (x) { document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView(); }`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by creating a pattern to any solution to make it a **generic** solution.

1. Mark your sections with an attribute of your liking, e.g.: scroll-to-id="1" and your sections can now look like `<div scroll-to-id="1"></div><div scroll-to-id="2"></div><div scroll-to-id="3"></div><div scroll-to-id="4"></div>`
2. Now make a function which will take the number as an input and scroll to the desired section. To get all targeted sections we can call the function `document.querySelectorAll('[scroll-to-id]')` to get all the elements with the attribute scroll-to-id.
3. Then find the element with the desired `scroll-to-id` to go to and scrollTo that element.

Full solution below:

```js
function scrollToSection(sectionId) {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('[scroll-to-id]');
  for(let section of sections) {
    if(section.getAttribute('scroll-to-id') == sectionId) {
      section.scrollIntoView();
      // scrollIntoView doesnot have the best browser supports. It is better to calculate the position of the section and do a scrollTo() or scrollBy()
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scrollToSection(1)">Scroll To 1</button>
<button onclick="scrollToSection(2)">Scroll To 2</button>
<button onclick="scrollToSection(3)">Scroll To 3</button>
<button onclick="scrollToSection(4)">Scroll To 4</button>

<div scroll-to-id="1">Hello 1</div>
<div scroll-to-id="2">Hello 2</div>
<div scroll-to-id="3">Hello 3</div>
<div scroll-to-id="4">Hello 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass element as an argument to your function

```
function scroll(el){
  el.scrollIntoView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow @Francy3k!

Just update your existing function to accept the ID of the section you'd like to scroll to:

```css
.buttons { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; background:white; padding:10px 0; text-align:center }
#sez1 { height:300px; background:green; vertical-align:middle }
#sez2 { height:300px; background:red; vertical-align:middle }
#sez3 { height:300px; background:blue; vertical-align:middle }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick="scrollToSection(1)">Go to SEZ1</button>
  <button onclick="scrollToSection(2)">Go to SEZ2</button>
  <button onclick="scrollToSection(3)">Go to SEZ3</button>
</div>
<div id="sez1">
</div>
<div id="sez2">
</div>
<div id="sez3">
</div>
<script>
  function scrollToSection(index) {
    const section = document.getElementById("sez" + index);
    section.scrollIntoView();
  }
</script>
```

Provided the section IDs follow the same convention, you should be able to use this pattern.